# Google Apps Marketplace Application Using Service Account

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, service-accounts

I have attempted to publish an application to the Google Apps Marketplace that uses a service account to act on behalf of users within a domain.  How does the installation flow differ based on whether the installing user is an administrator or a normal user since it requires the service account to be authorized in the Google Admin console?

I am getting push back during the application review asking why the app is requiring an admin to manually authorize the API scopes for the service account in the Google Admin Console.  If a Google Apps Administrator installs the application for the domain and consents to all of the application access, does that authorization apply for all users in the domain? I do not want all users in a domain to be prompted with the OAuth 2 consent screen.

Comment: When an admin installs an app (in this case one that requires domain wide delegation), the admin grants the app permissions to impersonate users in the domain. Also the admin is white listing this app to be used by the users. However, when the users try to use the app, they have to grant the app access to their information through Oauth 2. so they will be asked for consent  at least one time. is your use case different from this?

Comment: @Gerardo If simply by installing the app as an admin grants the app permission to impersonate users in the domain, then how would I get a user credential to authorize a request to an API if that user has not given individual consent?  The application needs access to user data without their individual consent since it retrieves User Usage Data and Drive data for files owned by each user in the domain.  Are service account applications not allowed in the Google Apps Marketplace?

Comment: Yes you can have service account in Google Apps Marketplace. Also, you can access user's data through impersonation with service account without their consent. You would need consent only if the users access directly to your application. Do you have enabled the check box to "Allow Individual Installs" in the Marketplace SDK?  If you do, this means that normal users (no admins) can install the app in their accounts. Since you are requesting actions that only admins can do/approve, it would be better to uncheck it. https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

Comment: @Gerardo If I understand correctly, if the application needs access to user data and the individual users do not give consent, it would require a service account to act on their behalf.  Is that correct?  This would require the admin to configure the service account and authorized API scopes in the Google Admin console so that the service account can run against individual user's data with out their consent.

Comment: As far as I know that would be correct. You can impersonate users even as soon as they are created, even before the user actually logs in for the first time. For this, the admin has to install the application in the domain. If the admin creates their own app (with the steps you mentioned) or if the app belongs to a 3rd party, in both scenarios the app needs to be installed in the domain.